# Using POST with HttpClient and Imgur API

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to upload an image using POST with the Imgur API but my code seems to return an object of FileList so I get the following error when trying to upload a file:

```sh
"Http failure response for https://api.imgur.com/3/upload?image=[object%20FileList]: 400 OK"
```

.html

```html
<input
  type="file"
  accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg"
  (change)="startUpload($event)"
/>
```

.ts

```
startUpload(event) {
  this.imgurProvider.uploadImage(event.target.files);
}
```

provider.ts

```
uploadImage(file: any, data: any = {}): Promise<any> {
    return this._getOptions().then(options => {
      return this.http.post('https://api.imgur.com/3/upload?image=' + file, data, options).toPromise();
    });
  }

  private _getOptions(): Promise<any> {
    return this._getIdToken().then(token => ({
      responseType: 'json',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + env.imgur.client_id
      })
    }));
  }

  currentUser(): firebase.User {
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
  }

  private _getIdToken(forceRefresh = false): Promise<string> {
    return this.currentUser().getIdToken(forceRefresh);
  }
```

Expected output should be a file itself but I'm getting an object

How can I get this code to upload a file using the API?

Comment: replace this `this.imgurProvider.uploadImage(event.target.files);` with `this.imgurProvider.uploadImage(event.target.files[0]);` and try it.

Comment: @alt255 Same response but now I get `"Invalid URL ([object File])"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to build a string, but instead of appending a string, you are trying to append a javascript object.

`[object%20FileList]` is the debug string for a JavaScript object of type FileList, and `[object File]` is the debug string for an object of type File.  My assumption is that you have to get the file's path out of the file object, which means you will need to do something like this:

```
let path = event.target.files[0].webkitRelativePath;

this.imgurProvider.uploadImage(path);
```

This is assuming you are receiving [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) type of file object, and that the API is expecting the file path.

Comment: "Http failure response for https://api.imgur.com/3/upload?image=: 400 OK"

Comment: That means the file path is empty.  I would suggest printing the contents of the file object to the console to see what's inside, so you can find the location of the path or filename.  It's not possible to guess what this will be without knowing more about your code.